# Self Signed Certificate in GitHub Webhook

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, githooks

I have got Jenkins server setup in Azure VM with self-signed certificate, when I tried to setup a webhook from GitHub server I getting error `"We couldn’t deliver this payload: certificate signed by unknown authority"`.

Do we have any way to import my CA file into GitHub trusted entry? I have tried searching in different forums but could see any response.

Thanks,

Comment: It is self signed certificate, so I don't have any specific CA file to embed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have admin access to the server you can install into it's cert store.

Most likely will never work for github.com, only for github enterprise.

https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.4/admin/configuration/configuring-your-enterprise/troubleshooting-ssl-errors#installing-self-signed-or-untrusted-certificate-authority-ca-root-certificates